# How to handle in spring validation of json request / bean if the json cannot be converted to the bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, validation

I have classic Spring MVC application.

I want to validate a Form using a corresponding Java Bean, annotated with JSR-303 validation annotation.

The form data is sent by an ajax call using JSON. This Json is converted to the target Java Bean with Jackson - automatically by spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ControllerConstants.CALCULATION_MAPPING_SUBMIT_FORM,method =  RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(@Valid @RequestBody MyFormBean bean, final BindingResult result) { 
... 
}
```

Problem is for example if I have an Integer field in my bean but, in JSON the values is not a number. In this case it cannot create the target bean, that cannot be validated. This situation cannot be solved with custom property editors, since there is no way to convert a a text that not represents an Integer to Integer.

It seems that this is solved in Grails, we get errors from validator (errors is domain object) which has to be created during the data binding. So I assume spring supports this, thus Grails just uses Spring's support)

So how to elegantly solve this situation to handle this "validation" error?

**UPDATE**

Actually I figured out, that is this is supported by spring if we use simple form submit. The problem is with integration of Jackson deserialized. It does not fills errors. Still how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options...

1. Have client side validation that would not allow the form to be submitted if the there are formatting issues.
2. On the server side you will have to have a mechanism of handling the exception that would catch it and report the problem back to client.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

Well not having client side validations may not be a good user experience. Users do not want to be reminded about validation errors after they have made a server round trip. However, if this is still a constraint have a look at following url and it gives elegant way of handling such issues and reporting informative error messages.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/

Comment: Hi, thx. The client side validation is that what we don't want, since we will have validation on 2 places. The 2. point is the question to how to do this elegantly!?

Comment: As I described in issue, form posting is by AJAX, a response will be a JSON with error messages if any, that will be used to update page (using JQuery) with error report, so no entire page is generated or updated. This is basically a client side validation taht goes to the server :)
Yes and the above code in the question is I created from the same link :) . But does not solves this probelm. And I expecting that spring has some solution for this, since I think is a quite common situation.